# Display sql query result in ejs file using node express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

newbie here, I want to display my sql query result into my ejs file but I don't know how to.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what have you done so far? ie sample code

Answer (score 4):

To use *ejs*, the Express render engine must be set.

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Then you can pass variables to templates a SQL query:

```
connection.query('SELECT 1', function (err, rows) {
  res.render('file.html', {
    'sql': rows
  });
});
```

In your template, then you can use code like so:

```
<%= sql.property %>
```

and even use scripts inside tags:

```
<% sql.forEach(function(field){ %>
  <%= field.property %>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EJS template url and send sql results using:

**.render()**